# Flutter and dart convert string to md5 then call as a string

Tags: flutter, dart, md5

For an api I am using, I have to convert a string password and a salt to a md5 string and call that string in a url post request,
my code looks like this:

```
generateMd5(String data) {
  var content = new Utf8Encoder().convert(sp);
  var md5 = crypto.md5;
  var digest = md5.convert(content);
  return digest.toString();
}
```

problem is i can't call it as a string. when i put "print(data)" it says its an Undefined name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method like this for your salted password token.

```
String makeToken(String password, String salt) =>
    md5.convert(utf8.encode(password + salt)).toString().toLowerCase();
```

Calling `print(makeToken('sesame', 'c19b2d'));` yields `26719a1196d2a940705a59634eb18eab` as shown in the test vector.

Supply the token as the `t` parameter and the salt as the `s` parameter of your API call.

You might find the following useful for your salt creation:

```
final _random = Random();

String randomToken(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(
      List.generate(length, (_) {
        var ch = _random.nextInt(52);
        if (ch > 25) {
          ch += 6;
        }
        return ch + 0x41;
      }),
    );

String newSalt() => randomToken(6);
```